# Razor pages always gives 404 unless using dotnet run

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I have a razor pages project that until recently worked fine, and on a colleagues computer works fine. On mine however, when running from Visual Studio or publishing to Azure via Visual studio it returns 404 for every page. Everything works as expected if I bypass Visual Studio and use `dotnet run` instead. Interestingly, previous commits that worked fine for me also now have the same problem. Which leads me to think its something environmental, but I can't track the cause down.

Comment: Seems that updating the version of visual studio magically fixed things here. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue .

- Try to use *dotnet build* instead of *dotnet run*.
- Also  check  you map  the path in azure  configuration for your application in the azure app  service

Comment: I think this helps me when running locally, but doesn't solve the problem when I publish to Azure unfortunately

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).